# .csv not a SequenceFile error on Select Hive Query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am quite a newbie to Spark and Scala ;)

Code summary :

Reading data from CSV files --> Creating A simple inner join on 2 Files --> Writing data to Hive table --> Submitting the job on the cluster

> Can you please help to identify what went wrong.
> The code is not really complex.
> The job is executed well on cluster.
> Therefore when I try to visualize data written on hive table I am facing issue.

hive> select * from Customers limit 10;

*Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: hdfs://m01.itversity.com:9000/user/itv000666/warehouse/updatedcustomers.db/customers/part-00000-348a54cf-aa0c-45b4-ac49-3a881ae39702_00000.c000 **.csv not a SequenceFile***

```
object LapeyreSparkDemo extends App {
  
  //Getting spark ready
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  sparkConf.set("spark.app.name","Spark for Lapeyre")
  
  //Creating Spark Session
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                          .config(sparkConf)
                          .enableHiveSupport()
                          .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","/user/itv000666/warehouse")
                          .getOrCreate()                       
  Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName).info("Spark Session Created Successfully")
  
  //Reading
  Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName).info("Data loading in DF started")
  val ordersSchema = "orderid Int, customerName String, orderDate String, custId Int, orderStatus 
  String, age String, amount Int" 
  val orders2019Df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header",true)
  .schema(ordersSchema)
  .option("path","/user/itv0006666/lapeyrePoc/orders2019.csv")
  .load
  val newOrder = orders2019Df.withColumnRenamed("custId", "oldCustId")
                             .withColumnRenamed("customername","oldCustomerName")
   
  val orders2020Df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header",true)
  .schema(ordersSchema)
  .option("path","/user/itv000666/lapeyrePoc/orders2020.csv")
  .load
  
  Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName).info("Data loading in DF complete")
  
  //processing
  Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName).info("Processing Started")
  val joinCondition = newOrder.col("oldCustId") === orders2020Df.col("custId")
  val joinType = "inner"
  val joinData = newOrder.join(orders2020Df, joinCondition, joinType)
                             .select("custId","customername")
  
  //Writing
  
  spark.sql("create database if not exists updatedCustomers")
                  
  joinData.write
  .format("csv")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .bucketBy(4, "custId")
  .sortBy("custId")
  .saveAsTable("updatedCustomers.Customers")
                        
  //Stopping Spark Session
  spark.stop()

}
```

Please let me know in case more information required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the result of `describe extended` to the question? Maybe it'll help. `DESCRIBE [DATABASE] [FORMATTED|EXTENDED] object_name`

Answer (score 0):

This is the culprit

```
joinData.write
.format("csv")
```

Instead used this and it worked.

```
joinData.write
.format("Hive")
```

Since I am writing data to hive table (orc format), the format should be "**Hive**" and not *csv*.

*Also, do not forget to enable hive support while creating spark session.
Also, In spark 2, bucketby & sortby is not supported. Maybe it does in Spark 3.*